# Looper.prepare exception using LocationManager in external Service

Tags: android, service, locationmanager, looper

I am getting the following exception when I try to use LocationManager within a custom class running in an external service:

```
*** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across        processes.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
        at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:1464)
        at android.location.LocationManager$GpsStatusListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:1464)
        at android.location.LocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(LocationManager.java:1503)
        at org.poseidon_project.contexts.hardware.GPSIndoorOutdoorContext.start(GPSIndoorOutdoorContext.java:97)
        at org.poseidon_project.context.management.ContextManager.addObserverRequirement(ContextManager.java:97)
        at org.poseidon_project.context.reasoner.ContextMapper.registerIndoorOutdoorsContext(ContextMapper.java:260)
        at org.poseidon_project.context.reasoner.ContextMapper.registerContext(ContextMapper.java:197)
        at org.poseidon_project.context.ContextReasonerCore.addContextRequirement(ContextReasonerCore.java:70)
        at org.poseidon_project.context.ContextReasonerService$1.addContextRequirement(ContextReasonerService.java:74)
        at org.poseidon_project.context.IContextReasoner$Stub.onTransact(IContextReasoner.java:74)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Now, I have read many answer relating back to the use of Looper, with stuff like:

```
    Looper.prepare;
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, mMinTime, mMinDistance, this, Looper.getMainLooper);
```

But this ends up not causing the Callback (onLocationChanged(Location location)) to be called when there is an update?

The class implements the LocationListener, which also invokes the LocatioManager methods:

```
public abstract class LocationContext extends ContextObserver implements LocationListener {

protected LocationManager mLocationManager;
private int mMinTime = 3000;
private int mMinDistance = 10;
private String mProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
private String mIdealProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;


public LocationContext (Context c) {
    super(c);
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public LocationContext (Context c, ContextReceiver cr) {
    super(c, cr);
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public LocationContext (Context c, ContextReceiver cr, int minTime, int minDistance, String name) {
    super(c, cr, name);
    mMinTime = minTime;
    mMinDistance = minDistance;
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public LocationContext (Context c, ContextReceiver cr, int minTime, int minDistance, String provider, String name) {
    super(c, cr, name);
    mMinTime = minTime;
    mMinDistance = minDistance;
    mProvider = provider;
    mIdealProvider = provider;
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public boolean start() {

    //new Thread(new Runnable() {
    //  @Override
    //  public void run() {
            //Looper.prepare();

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, mMinTime, mMinDistance, this);
            //handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            //Looper.loop();
    //  }
    //}).start();


    mIsRunning = true;
    //Looper.loop();
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean pause() {
    return stop();
}


@Override
public boolean resume() {
    return start();
}

@Override
public boolean stop() {
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    mIsRunning = false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    checkContext(location);

}


protected abstract void checkContext(Location location);

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    if (provider.equals(mIdealProvider)) {
        mProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

        if (! mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(mProvider)) {
            Intent gpsOptionIntent = new Intent (android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(gpsOptionIntent);
        }
    }

}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    if ((provider.equals(mIdealProvider)) && (! provider.equals(mProvider))) {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        mProvider = provider;
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, mMinTime, mMinDistance, this);
    }
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public int getMinTime() {
    return mMinTime;
}

public void setMinTime(int mMinTime) {
    this.mMinTime = mMinTime;
}

public int getMinDistance() {
    return mMinDistance;
}

public void setMinDistance(int mMinDistance) {
    this.mMinDistance = mMinDistance;
}
```

I don't really understand how to use the Looper in my situation. Can someone help? I understand the answer "run in UI thread" but this is a single service app, there is no UI, so I don't think I can do it in the UI thread?

****UPDATE*****Solution Found******

I believe I found a solution. The class in question was an abstract class, which I was extending by a few classes that did various Location based operations.

In the LocationContext abstract class I used:

```
 mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, mMinTime, mMinDistance,this, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

And in an implementation class (for example one for analysing GPS satellite status) I placed it in a new Thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            GPSIndoorOutdoorContext.super.start();
            mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsListener);
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

`mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, mMinTime, mMinDistance, this);`

is getting called from a NON UI Thread. Make sure you call your init or call your method in the UI Thread. You're probably initiating `LocationContext` or calling `start` method from a NON UI Thread, which you can't do. To request location updates, it must be called from the UI Thread.

Comment: The problem is, this is a service that runs without a UI. It is supposed to be a service that other apps (with UIs) call.

I don't know how I can do it on the UI thread? This code works fine if I try it with a test activity in the same app, but when it called from a different app, the exception is thrown.

Comment: I do not understand how I can, as I said this service is normally in a separate process to any app with an Activity. runOnUIThread is an Activity method...
Is there a way I can use the Looper to get around this?